# xPaw Minecraft Server Query

Tags: php, class, minecraft

Can someone help me get just the Hostname from this Minecraft Query by xPaw.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query

I believe i add something after GetInfo( ).

```
<?php
    require('MinecraftQuery.class.php');

    $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( 'localhost', 25565 );

       print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ));
    }
    catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery.class.php#L105, you should be able to do:-

```
$info = $Query->GetInfo();
echo $info['hostname'];
```

Comment: Hello. I'm using https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query solution

I got some issue with response HostName:

    ?8?m-]?5?m--?2?l ?b?l+!6?c?l7/2,$ ?5?m--?8?m[-?c ?f?lKavBuy.Ru ?e?l1.8-1.10 ?b?l?e?lSurvival?b?l?b,?a?lMarry?b?l?b,?b?lSkyWars,?c?lClans?b?l?b,?f?lParkour

How to convert it into human view?